# Does Fog Cloud grant enemies disadvantage on spells requiring a successful Saving Throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

If for example my Tempest Cleric were to cast Fog Cloud into a room of enemies would they roll at a disadvantage when my Wizard companion hurls a Shatter into that room?

Answer (score 10):

Thick fog, as produced by *fog cloud*, causes those within it to “effectively suffer[] from the blinded condition” (PHB, p. 183). The Blinded condition does not affect saving throws, only ability checks ([which saving throws are *not*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53941/what-is-the-difference-between-ability-checks-and-saving-throws)) and attack rolls they make or made against them (PHB, p. 290).

Hence, no — being in a *fog cloud* won't impose disadvantage on anyone's saving throws against *shatter*.