# Can a Bard use Inspiration Dice and Cutting Words when casting a spell with a Wisdom Save?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, bard, inspiration

I am playing a level 5 bard, stolen away from my group to the underdark by a mindflayer. I have 28 HP, two third level spells slots, and no weapons.

I'm in deep trouble, but I think if I cast **Suggestion** and suggest the mindflayer takes me back to my group, I think my group can defeat it.

I want to give **Suggestion** everything I've got - use Inspiration Dice to make the check higher and use Cutting Words against the creature's Wisdom Saving Throw.

Can I do that in the same turn?

Comment: How are you using an inspiration die to make the check higher?

Comment: [Important related reading](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53941/what-is-the-difference-between-ability-checks-and-saving-throws).

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking re the inspiration dice. Pity I can't use cutting words like that. Yeah, my best shot is just casting it twice.

Comment: @LJxhanswers It looks like you've accidentally created more than one account. You will be unable to comment on or accept answers to this question until you [merge your accounts using the instructions in the help centre](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 8):

### You can't use Bardic Inspiration at all

Suggestion forces a saving throw on your target's part. Even if you could use Inspiration on your own ability checks -- which you can't, that's a high level ability -- it won't apply to this scenario.

### You can't Cutting Words a saving throw

Your target's saving throws are unaffected by Cutting Words. You can only use that against ability checks, damage rolls, or attack rolls.

### You *can* cast the spell twice

Since you have two slots left, if it succeeds the first saving throw, you can always cast it again. Effectively, this is burning through everything you have, but the Illithid has to pass both saving throws, which is similar to disadvantage.

Comment: Note that you can't cast it again until a later round.

Comment: You can't use Inspiration on your own ability checks?

Comment: @KyleW Sadly, not unless you are a level 14 College of Lore bard. The College of Lore feature 'Peerless Skill' allows you to spend an inspiration die on your own ability checks.

Comment: @Jon Is this supposed to refer to Bardic Inspiration?

Comment: @KyleW Correct. You can't use inspiration on yourself until you have 'Peerless Skill'. Even then, it's use is limited to ability checks, not saving throws or attack rolls.

Comment: @aramis Only if it's treated as a combat situation with initative rolls